# Call to a member function address() on null

Tags: php, laravel-5

I got an error:

> Symfony \ Component \ Debug \ Exception \ FatalThrowableError (E_ERROR)
>   Call to a member function address() on null

**AddressController.php**

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request,[
            'fname'=>'required',
            'lname'=>'required',
            'addressline'=>'required',
            'city'=>'required',
            'phone'=>'required |regex:/^[0-9\-\+]{9,15}$/',

        ]);

        Auth::user()->address()->create($request->all());


        Order::createOrder();


        return redirect('/');
    }
```

Comment: Can you please share more details?

Comment: Call to a member function address() on null ... basically means your auth::user is null. The user isn't found.

Comment: improved formatting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [DevionNL](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8931764/devionnl) said, this error message means that `Auth::user()` is null.

Therefore it is better to test this before calling the `address()` method:

```
if (!is_null(Auth::user())) {
    Auth::user()->address()->create($request->all());
} else {
    //handle the error
}
```